# How to give each student a unique ID after being created by the user on JAVA program

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am working on a school project that basically allows the user to create, edit or view students. Once a student is created, they each get assigned a unique ID like 1, 2, 3, etc. All the functionally of creation, editing and displaying is working but I am stuck on have to give them a unique ID after created. Here is the code I have and in the // commented areas is what I attempted to do but I am not sure if its right. Any ideas will be very appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class MidTermProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Here is the sample of menu choices for Main Menu.");
        
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to University Enrollment" + "\n1. Create Student" + "\n2. Edit Student" + "\n3. Display Student" + "\n0. --- Quit ---");
        
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid choice(1-10, 0 to Quit) :");
        int userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        if(userInput == 1) {
            CreateStudent();
        } else if(userInput == 2) {
            EdithStudent();
        } else if(userInput == 3) {
            DisplayStudent();
        } else if(userInput == 0) {
            System.out.print("Done");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid Option, Please try again.");
            userInput = keyboard.nextInt();
            if(userInput == 1) {
                CreateStudent();
            } else if(userInput == 2) {
                EditStudent();
            } else if(userInput == 3) {
                DisplayStudent();
            } else if(userInput == 0) {
                System.out.print("Done");
            }
        }

    }
    
    public static void CreateStudent() throws IOException {
        String FullName;
        String address;
        String city;
        String state;
        int StudentID;
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        FileOutputStream fstream =
                new FileOutputStream("StudentInfo.dat");
        DataOutputStream outputFile =
                new DataOutputStream(fstream);
        
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter your information bellow.\n" + "\nFull Name: ");
        FullName = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeUTF(FullName);
        
        System.out.print("Address: ");
        address = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeUTF(address);
        
        System.out.print("City: ");
        city = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeUTF(city);
        
        System.out.print("State: ");
        state = keyboard.nextLine();
        outputFile.writeUTF(state);
        
        //allowed the user to select their own ID number
        System.out.print("Please get a Student ID(1-10): ");
        //Store the selected number on StudentID
        StudentID = keyboard.nextInt();
        //The for loop will increment index each time a user is created
        for(int index = 0; index == StudentID; index++) {
            //The if statement will compare index and StudentID, if equal will ask the user to enter a different number
            if(index == StudentID) {
                System.out.print("The selected ID has been selected already, Please select a different ID");
                StudentID = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
        }
        //write the number in the file
        outputFile.writeInt(StudentID);
        
        System.out.print("Successfully Created");
        
    }

    public static void EditStudent() throws IOException {
        String editName;
        String editaddress;
        String editCity;
        String editState;
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        RandomAccessFile file = 
                new RandomAccessFile("StudentInfo.dat", "rw");
        file.seek(0);
        
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter NEW information bellow.\n" + "\nFull Name: ");
        editName = keyboard.nextLine();
        file.writeUTF(editName);
        
        System.out.print("Address: ");
        editaddress = keyboard.nextLine();
        file.writeUTF(editaddress);
        
        System.out.print("City: ");
        editCity = keyboard.nextLine();
        file.writeUTF(editCity);
        
        System.out.print("State: ");
        editState = keyboard.nextLine();
        file.writeUTF(editState);
        
        file.close();
        
        System.out.print("Successfully Edited");
    }

    public static void DisplayStudent() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("StudentInfo.dat");
        DataInputStream inputFile = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        
        String student;
        boolean endOfFile = false;
        
        while(!endOfFile)
        {
            try
            {
                student = inputFile.readUTF();
                System.out.print(student + " ");
            }
            catch (EOFException e)
            {
                endOfFile = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nDone");
        
        inputFile.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, following [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) makes your code more readable. So use lowercase first when naming a variable: `studentId` rather than `StudentId`. Initial-caps is for class names.

In your create student method, your `for` loop makes no sense.

```
for(int index = 0; index == StudentID; index++) {
    //The if statement will compare index and StudentID, if equal will ask the user to enter a different number
    if(index == StudentID) {
        System.out.print("The selected ID has been selected already, Please select a different ID");
        StudentID = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
}
```

A `for` loop simply increments the index defined in the first clause, stepping the increment according to the third clause, until the second clause proves `true`.

So in your code, if the user enters `4`, your loop counts 0, 1, 2,  3, 4 «bingo». Now that we reached the user’s specified number, we go on to ask them for another number. And we’re done. But that process is illogical.

That code fails to accomplish your goal of checking for existing students. You need to review all existing students one-by-one. Compare each existing student ID against the desired ID. Only after exhausting the list of all known students should we use the desired ID. If we find a match on an existing student, then we break out of the loop to ask the user for another choice of ID. And we need another outer loop to continue this “ask, search, ask again if needed” process until an unused desired ID is determined.

**Big tip**: If you write out your problem statement and solution attempt as plain prose, similar to what I just did in the paragraph above, your programming will go more smoothly. And your written prose will be fodder for writing helpful comments in your source code.